# 2-axis line chart in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I've set up a Google Sheets to compare one set of statistics against another. The statistics are for traffic vs. an action. The actions only happen once a day and not every day whereas the traffic has more volume and happens every day.

What I want to show is a 2-line line chart with two axes so that I can run the two lines against one another. At the moment all I've been able to make is a chart with two lines, but both using the same axis. This means that the action line always is sitting at either `0` or `1`, whereas the traffic line is going up to `30` but they are both drawn against the same axis so you can't really read the chart well to see a coloration.

I've linked [a copy of the Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjhmNC-l_CS3dFhlMU5KT3lPRDZoSkdjRDJ2aG9NVkE&usp=sharing) and a mock-up of what I'm trying to achieve here:

[image: chart]

Answer (score 26):

What you need to do is a few steps:

1. **Insert** to **Chart** then add your Data Series, as you normally would with a Single Axis chart.
2. (Optional) Change chart type to **Line**. You can change it to anything else later. Line seems to be a safe bet for the later options to appear. Not sure if this step is by Google design...
3. Right-click on the chart and select **Series**.
4. Change **Apply Series** to whichever Data Series you want to move to the Second Axis.
5. Change Axis to **Right Axis**.
6. Now you can go back to **Chart type** to make it a scatter, or bar, or anything else - the program will remember the Axis assigned to the Data Series, regardless of whatever options may be available.

tldr; the Google Support answer is broken for a few chart types. Do your Axis assignments with Line charts, and change the Chart Type after.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your example image relates to your example data because with your data I get:

[image: WA40791 example]

but at least the above shows a [secondary vertical axis](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2451203?hl=en) is possible (though only for certain chart types) and it did seem necessary to replace the blanks in your ColumnC with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the need to replace blanks by going into `Chart editor`, `Customize`, `Chart style`, and enable `Plot null values`.

Comment: This answers a question OP did not ask.